# How to make bar plot with converting the month column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this. The month column is in type of string. 
I want to make a bar plot from 201501 to 201505 with x axis is month while y axis is total_gmv. x format is like Jan,2015   Feb 2015. So how can I realize it using python?  Thanks.

```
month   total_gmv
201501  NaN
201502  2.824294e+09
201503  7.742665e+09
201504  2.024132e+10
201505  6.705012e+10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous replies have some clues but its does not show exhaustive answer.
You have to set custom xtick labels and rotate it like here:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'month': ['201501', '201502', '201503', '201504', '201505'], 
     'total_gmv': [np.nan, 2.824294e+09, 7.742665e+09, 2.024132e+10, 6.705012e+10]})
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%Y%m', errors='ignore')

ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_xticklabels(df['month'].dt.strftime('%b, %Y'))
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to force month to be a timestamp and then set it as an index and plot it.

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.month)
ax = df.set_index('month').plot(kind='bar')
```

And you might have to change the date format.

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter= mdates.DateFormatter('%b, %Y')
```

Check [here for more](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'month': ['201501', '201502', '201503', '201504', '201505'], 
     'total_gmv': [np.nan, 2.824294e+09, 7.742665e+09, 2.024132e+10, 6.705012e+10]})

df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%Y%m').dt.month
df = df.set_index('month')

print df
df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Result:

```
          total_gmv
month              
1               NaN
2      2.824294e+09
3      7.742665e+09
4      2.024132e+10
5      6.705012e+10
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Actually I want the x axis to be labeled as Jan.2015  feb.2015

Answer (score 1):

You should use `matplotlib.pyplot` and `calendar` module.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import calendar

#change the numeric representation to texts (201501 -> Jan,2015)
df['month_name'] = [','.join([calendar.month_name[int(date[-1:-3]),date[-3:]] for date in df['month']

#change the type of df['month'] to int so plt can read it
df['month'].apply(int)

x = df['month']
y = df['total_gmv']
plt.bar(x, y, align = 'center')

#i'm not sure if you have to change the Series to a list; do whatever works
plt.xticks =(x, df['month_name']) 
plt.show()
```